# PDFBox: retrieve multiple textfields with the same name

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to retrieve some input fields from a PDF (2.0.7) with PDFBox without success.

In detail, i have the following (PDF available here: https://file.io/q56S4r or here http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=38385451581058382678 ) . The current PDF contains 3 textfields with the same name "**Text1**" . In addition Acrobat PRO represents those fields like seen in the screenshot from Acrobat Pro:

[image]

The following code below instead of retrieving 3 fields, it returns a list with just this object "**Text1{type: PDTextField value: null}**"

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(input);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
for (PDField field : fields) {
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to read in some way all fields even if they have the same name? Is this a bad practice maybe and the correct answer is to give unique names?

Comment: Can you upload you PDF file to a hoster that is not trying to install malware on your computer?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find a provider which is add free. Please try from google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9B-OjXnFv_VFg5ZGJoazN5VUk/view?ts=59aea777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the PDF has only one field defined. If you open the PDF in Acrobat Reader and enter a value in one of the fields, the other two fields are immediately filled with the same value. If you really want three different values, you need to specify a unique name for each of the fields.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question.